# Meu código em C contém alguns erros (Lista Estrutura de Dados)

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Criei um Player de música para uma disciplina de Estrutura de Dados utilizando Lista Duplamente Encadeada e Circular. Porém, está apresentando alguns erros e não estou conseguindo visualizar onde. Alguém poderia me ajudar ? Talvez seja erro de lógica e/ou erro de sintaxe.

A opção play mostra o nome da música atual e passa para a próxima. A opção showPlaylist mostra todas as 7 músicas que a playlist contém.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Music {
    char name[25];
    struct Music *previous;
    struct Music next; 
} music;

music *playlist;


void start(){
    music *m1=malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m1->name, "MUSIC1");
    playlist = m1;
    music *m2=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m2->name, "MUSIC2");
    m1->next = m2;
    m2->previous = m1; //ERRO2
    music *m3=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m3->name, "MUSIC3");
    m2->next = m3;
    m3->previous = m2;
    music *m4=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m4->name, "MUSIC4");
    m3->next = m4;
    m4->previous = m3;
    music *m5=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m5->name, "MUSIC5");
    m4->next = m5;
    m5->previous = m4;
    music *m6=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m6->name, "MUSIC6");
    m5->next = m5;
    m6->previous = m5;
    music *m7=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m7->name, "MUSIC7");
    m6->next = m7;
    m7->previous = m6;
    m7->next = m1;
    m1->previous = m7;
}

void play(){
    printf("%s\n",playlist->name);
    playlist=playlist->next;
}

void showPlaylist(){
    music *aux = playlist;
    int i = 1;
    while (i<=7){
        printf("%s\n",aux->name);
        aux = aux->next;
        i++;
    }
}

void main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int op;
    start();
    do
    {
        printf("1 - Play music\n");
        printf("2 - Show Playlist\n");
        printf("0 - Exit\n");
        printf("Choose Option:");
        scanf("%d",op);
        int n;
        switch(op) {
            case 1: play();
            case 2: showPlaylist(); 
                    break;
            case 0: printf("Byee!\n");
                    break;
            default: printf("What?!\n");
        }       
    } while (op!=0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código tem vários errinhos, vamos por partes:

1 - Você esqueceu de incluir o `<stdlib.h>` no seu código (para a função malloc);

2 - Sua struct deveria ser assim:

```
typedef struct Music {
    char name[25];
    struct Music *previous;
    struct Music *next; // ponteiro para next, não a struct next
} music;
```

3 - Você esqueceu de converter o `(void*)` que é retornado pelo malloc para (*music) no m1, logo deveria ser assim: `music *m1= (music*) malloc(sizeof(music));`

4 - A função `scanf` recebe ponteiros para variáveis, logo deve ser: `scanf("%d", &op);`

O código arrumado no final pode ser:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Music {
    char name[25];
    struct Music *previous;
    struct Music *next;
} music;

music *playlist;


void start(){
    music *m1= (music*) malloc(sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m1->name, "MUSIC1");
    playlist = m1;
    music *m2=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m2->name, "MUSIC2");
    m1->next = m2;
    m2->previous = m1; //ERRO2
    music *m3=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m3->name, "MUSIC3");
    m2->next = m3;
    m3->previous = m2;
    music *m4=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m4->name, "MUSIC4");
    m3->next = m4;
    m4->previous = m3;
    music *m5=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m5->name, "MUSIC5");
    m4->next = m5;
    m5->previous = m4;
    music *m6=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m6->name, "MUSIC6");
    m5->next = m5;
    m6->previous = m5;
    music *m7=(music *)malloc (sizeof(music));
    strcpy(m7->name, "MUSIC7");
    m6->next = m7;
    m7->previous = m6;
    m7->next = m1;
    m1->previous = m7;
}

void play(){
    printf("%s\n",playlist->name);
    playlist=playlist->next;
}

void showPlaylist(){
    music *aux = playlist;
    int i = 1;
    while (i<=7){
        printf("%s\n",aux->name);
        aux = aux->next;
        i++;
    }
}

void main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int op;
    start();
    do
    {
        printf("1 - Play music\n");
        printf("2 - Show Playlist\n");
        printf("0 - Exit\n");
        printf("Choose Option:");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        int n;
        switch(op) {
            case 1: play();
            case 2: showPlaylist();
                    break;
            case 0: printf("Byee!\n");
                    break;
            default: printf("What?!\n");
        }
    } while (op!=0);
}
```

*Nota: Não arrumei/melhorei outras coisas que podem ser arrumadas/melhoradas pois só arrumei o que pode estar impedindo o desenvolvimento do seu programa.*

Comment: Muitos erros meu por falta de atenção. Obrigado Adriano pela revisão no código e pelo auxílio. Aos poucos vou melhorando.